# sparql query to get all individual of specific class using data value

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I have an ontology that contains two classes (course,lesson) the course has a data properties called code of type string

How to get all individuals from specific class with specific data properties value

here is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general pattern is something like this:

```
SELECT ?individual
WHERE { ?individual a <uri-of-specific-class> ;
                    <uri-of-property> ?propertyValue .
        FILTER(STR(?propertyValue) = "expected value")
}
```

You will need to adapt this with the details of your specific ontology (the URIs of your class names and properties), but it shows the general approach. I would also suggest that you try out a SPARQL tutorial, there's several good ones online for you to find.

Comment: PREFIX lumiere: <http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#>
SELECT ?individual
WHERE { ?individual a lumiere:Course ;
                    lumiere:Code ?propertyValue .
        FILTER(STR(?propertyValue) = "CS101")
}

Comment: Can I use multiple filter ?

Comment: You can use as many as you like, or you can combine multiple conditions in a single filter with boolean operators: `FILTER(condition1 && condition2)`